# pyside pyqt4 conflict in ipython when running morphotester.py

Tags: ipython, pyqt4, pyside, canopy

Trying to run a package in canopy, when I run the package it causes a conflict as pyside appears to be the default whereas the package calls for pyqt4, how can I disable pyside in Ipython, or otherwise deal with the issue?

```
%run "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\morphotester-master\morphotester-master\Morpho.py"
C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1350: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
WARNING:traits.has_traits:DEPRECATED: traits.has_traits.wrapped_class, 'the 'implements' class advisor has been deprecated. Use the 'provides' class decorator.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\morphotester-master\morphotester-master\Morpho.py in <module>()
     25 from mayavi.core.ui.api import MlabSceneModel
     26 from tvtk.pyface.scene_editor import SceneEditor
---> 27 from PyQt4 import QtGui
     28 
     29 class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\qt_loaders.pyc in load_module(self, fullname)

ImportError: 
    Importing PyQt4 disabled by IPython, which has
    already imported an Incompatible QT Binding: pyside
```

Comment: The package is morphotester.py from https://github.com/juliawinchester/morphotester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Canopy / Edit / Preferences / Python, disable Pylab mode, or set it to "Inline (SVG)"